# how send back a child in java?

Tags: java, jform

I added a TextPane in jForm.  The form has a menu bar but the menus are displayed on the back of the TextPane.   How can i fix it?

Comment: could you please add some code?...that will make it 100 times easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you mean a `JFrame`, not a `JForm` (whatever that is). Not to be rude, but if you can't even tell us the objects you're using, you'll probably not get much great assistance.

So, are you doing something like this in your init code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Blah");
frame.setJMenuBar(new JMenuBar());
frame.setContentPane(new JTextPane());
```

I use `new` objects here, but they could be local or member variables.